# MySQL -- using only SQL, how to return the results of an alternate query if the current query returned empty?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have this person table

```
id        name       gender 
1         John       male
2         Kurt       male
3         Tyler      male
4         Matthias   male
```

And we have this query

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE gender = female
```

which would return empty

Is there a way in MySQL(inside the SQL) to run and return the results of an alternate query if the current query returned empty?

Something like "if there are no rows returned, return rows with gender = male instead"

Comment: You could do that with `UNION` and subquery, but you'd better implement that logic in your programming language (that is why I don't give you the complete query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this only works in stored procedures and functions because of `IF THEN / ELSE` statement disposal.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM person WHERE gender = female) THEN
  SELECT * FROM person WHERE gender = female
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM person WHERE gender = male
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: IF THEN/ELSE is only available inside of stored procedures and functions.

Comment: @TehShrike - is MySQL really so brainless in that way ? I know only MSSQL and I thought this can work. I can't test it anywhere so I'll add a remark to my answer so upvoters may take their votes back :) Anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yep, tested it and didn't work in MySQL. However there is an IF() function as opposed to the IF operator. Didn't work either but good to know.

Comment: @arvinism Aye, that sort of logic is only available in certain places in MySQL.  Your example would work for him - in a function.  Otherwise, he'd probably want to use 2 queries, and application logic.